# Jquery xml parse question

Tags: jquery

I have an xml which contains reference to internal vocabulary

How can I use jquery to resolve this reference and parse successfully..

XML

```
<something>
<element reference="../../../../test"/>
</something>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated..

Comment: Is your XML a string readily available or is it returned via AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of jQuery (1.5.1), yes.

```
var XML = '<something><element reference="../../../../test"/></something>';
var xmlDoc = $( $.parseXML(XML) );

//Alerts out "../../../../test"
alert( xmlDoc.find("element").attr("reference") );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nKAGP/

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. to download the referenced document,
2. to parse this document.

You may perform an AJAX request with jQuery, which will do both steps:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "URL of the document (possibly relative)",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    $(xml). ...  // now you may use jQuery functions to explore the document
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** The URL document may be retrieved from your first XML document using motionman95's answer. Then you pass it to the above and you get the *referenced* XML document.